# Clean compile, but run-time error: ASP.NET CS1513: } expected error on page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Stumped. No idea on this one. I get a clean compilation but this run-time error.

Error message is:

```
Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS1513: } expected

Source Error:


Line 10911:        }
Line 10912:        
Line 10913:        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
Line 10914:        private global::System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel @__BuildControlpnlData() {
Line 10915:            global::System.Web.UI.UpdatePanel @__ctrl;

Source File: c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\6648c2c6\bd7d66c0\App_Web_mysubscriptions.aspx.cdcab7d2.kpmgh13c.0.cs    Line: 10913
```

This is a generated file, classic asp.net, not mvc. Someone else can load exactly the same project from source control and have no problems running it.  I have deleted the project and pulled the same code from source control and I get the same error. I have deleted all temporary files in the location indicated and it still generates the same error when it generates the new files.

The file it refers to does not exist. The page it seems to come from inherits from a basepage. There is no line 10913, nothing even close. This is not my code, it's something from the .net system.

All of which is irrelevant anyway as I already said - other people can pull this code from the repository and run it just fine.

Comment: You have the path to the generated source file that fails to compile at the end of the error. Open that file, check the line where the problem is and then trace it back to where in your code the problem occurs (or just clean out the "Temporary ASP.Net Files" folder and hope it solves it).

Comment: Well I was going to say your comment was nonsense as other developers in the office can happily compile & run the same code from a repository. Then I waded through a few thousand lines of generated code and cross-matched it back to one of the base pages where a "<% " was missing.  Curiously after adding it back in (it caused the code to work) and "updating to latest version" from the repository, it left that line of code alone, so somehow visualsvn seems to ignore "<%" entries?  Anyhow, you live and learn. Cheers for the tip that moved me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same problem a few minutes ago. Karl's comment contained the solution, so I am posting it here in case the comments get auto-purged someday.

The error page will mention the file which contains the missing `}`, it's an auto-generated file in the ASP.NET temporary files folder. Open that file, check what is wrong and trace it back to your source code. If you are getting a clean build, then the error is probably in a view.